# Yii2: очистка формы на pjax

Tags: php, yii2

Имеется форма, находящаяся в index-вьюхе:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'formPjax']);$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contactForm', 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true]]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['autofocus' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['autofocus' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'type' => 'email', 'id' => 'email']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['autofocus' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Phone', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textArea(['autofocus' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Message', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true, 'rows' => 5]) ?>
 <?=  Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg']); if($isSave === true)  echo "<b style='float:none' class='navbar-brand'>Ваше сообщение было доставлено</b>"; $model = new Order();?>
```

Вот так она сразу рендерится: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, что у меня после нажатия на кнопку отправки формы форма очищается (**к этому и стремлюсь**), но после обновления страницы данные возвращаются в текстовые поля. Будто они где-то записались и постоянно считываются обратно.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    $isSave = true;
    $model = new Order();
}
...
```

Comment: пробовал так, без изменений всё остается:
жму на кнопку - форма очищается - обновляюсь - форма заполнена предыдущими данными.

Comment: Alexandr написал верно, проверьте повторно ваш код